# How to search by many value in array using mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, mongodb-query

I have data object like as :

```
{
  "openingTime": ['Mon','Fri','Sat','Sun']
}
```

If I search with string 'Mon Sat Sun', return TRUE.
If I search with string 'Mon Web Sun', return FALSE.

Please help me, or give a keyword. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Tks for the updating. I updated some tags, then the format of JSON code was lose

Comment: Are you doing a "$or" search?  db.hello.find({ $or: [ { "openingTime" : 'Mon' }, { "openingTime" : 'Wed' } ] })

Comment: Tks @KenCheung. But I think it is not optimize if the length of input is unstable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) which is basically an `$and` condition but with nicer syntax:

```js
db.hello.find({ "opening_time": { "$all": [ "Mon", "Sat", "Sun" ] } })
```

Or in the failing case:

```js
db.hello.find({ "opening_time": { "$all": [ "Mon", "Wed", "Sun" ] } })
```

Since "Wed" is not a value in the array then it is not a match.

This is the nicer form of:

```js
db.hello.find({ "$and": [ 
    { "opening_time": "Mon" },
    { "opening_time": "Sat" },
    { "opening_time": "Sun" }
]})
```

Which means you need "all" of the conditions to be met in order to make this true.

If you have a string, then just "split" it to form the array argument:

```js
var string = "Mon Sat Sun";

db.hello.find({ "opening_time": { "$all": string.split(" ") } })
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Your way looks great!